# When each of objects is respectively responding to different subjects, should I use "and" or "or"?

Tags: grammar

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=25)

> we
>   talked in the last video about
>   horizontal lines having a gradient of
>   zero whilst upwards and downwards
>   sloping lines having positive or
>   negative gradients respectively

mathematically, upwards sloping lines have positive gradients, downwards sloping lines have negative gradients.

consider "upwards and downwards sloping lines having positive or negative gradients respectively" as a separate sentence, how to re-write it in a non-confusing and concise way, expression_1, expression_2 or some other else?

expression_1

upwards **and** downwards sloping lines have positive or negative gradients respectively

expression_2

upwards **or** downwards sloping lines have positive or negative gradients respectively

Comment: There is no "right" answer, as it's mostly a matter of personal style.  Personally, I prefer **and** for both parts: *"upwards **and** downwards sloping lines have positive **and** negative gradients, respectively"*.  However, this is not something I would say, but probably not *write*.  Potentially confusing sentences like this should be re-written in a non-confusing way.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comments. How to re-write it in a non-confusing and concise way?